# Парсинг html страницы, помещение результата в xml файл

Tags: xml, c#, html, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте, очень срочно нужна помощь по C#, необходимо парсить html страницу и запихать результаты в xml файл.
Спарсить необходимо [эту страницу](http://bus42.info/navi/schedule/shedule.printable.php?type=trol&way=1&date=1111100&direction=AB&waypoint=all). А запихивать данные нужно в xml такого образца:

```
<ost ostan="название остановки">
     <vrem chas="час" min="минуты через пробел"></vrem>
</ost>
```

Comment: И что вы уже пробовали? В чем проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Берёте [вот эту](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) библиотеку и парсите с лёгкостью.